# Which do I use for building simple GUIs with matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, user-interface

I I just want to build a simple GUI (like button, scale changing parameter values) to update matplotlib plot using python. Which package is easier for me to use? TKinter, PyQt5, wxPython, etc??? I am not a  software developer. I am an engineer. Just use python for data analysis and plotting. I like to have a simple gui to changing parameter values to update plot.

I am thinking if tkinter would be best? I came across the following example. It is pretty easier. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

[Embed a pyplot in a tkinter window and update it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25498937/embed-a-pyplot-in-a-tkinter-window-and-update-it)

Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what did you use in the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you are working on small projects then you should use Tkinter as it is easy use and user friendly but when you working on big projects then you need to use PyQt5 as it will give you lots of functionalities and it is easier to use too.
Believe it takes very less time to understand this library in python.
For learning purpose you can visit pdfdrive.com and download your free eBooks.

Comment: Thanks Md Irshad.  You said PyQt5 is easy to use? Thanks